# viewWithTag used in conjunction with IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a bunch of views, each with 2 labels in them that are exactly the same. the labels all are tagged 1 and 2 in each view.

Now i wasnt using an `IBOutletCollection` before and had a reference to each of these views (which was unnecessary) and was getting a reference to the labels in the views like so:

```
l1 = (UILabel*)[_labels4 viewWithTag:1]; //_labels4 is a UIView with 2 labels in it
l2 = (UILabel*)[_labels4 viewWithTag:2];
```

which worked fine, but the code was becoming bloated, so i wanted to start using an `IBOutletCollection` so i can cycle through all the views with a for loop

so when i did that it seemed to work fine, except the labels now were becoming `UIViews` instead of `UILabels`

```
for(UIView *view in self.labelViews){ //self.labelViews is the collection of UIViews aka _labels4 + others

    UILabel *l1 = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *l2 = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:2];

    l2.text = @"Reference"; //crash because unrecognised selector 'setText' sent to UIView
}
```

does anyone by any chance know why? you can check out some more detailed code [over here](http://pastebin.com/nTtRrKXu)

to help clear up misconceptions:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably have views somewhere in your view hierarchy (that are in your collection) that are not `UILabels` but still have tags. It is probably grabbing one of these at some point. Check in IB that only `UILabels` have tag values 1 & 2 (that are in your collection).

Comment: it looks as if you are looking for the UIView in the for loop, not a UILabel. Try changing the UIView to UILabel

Comment: that is intentional, im trying to loop through a bunch of `UIViews` that have labels in them, that are both tagged 1 and 2. Im not looping through the labels inside the `UIViews`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the problem, and sorry, it wasnt anything anyone here could have spotted. Somewhere in this project having the views set as 0,1,2,3 etc causes them to get modified by something (not sure what yet, im doing maintenance on a project that is not my own) so setting the tags to something random like 900,901... etc seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your self.labelViews there is a UIView hiding in there that is not a UILabel

In the code you posted can you change the following:

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *labelViews;

Should read

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labelViews;

Comment: No, it is meant to be UIView, because the labels are inside a UIView. im trying to loop through the UIViews and then access the UILabels with the tags

Comment: if that is the case then you need to again go through each of the sub views in the UIViews to get the UILabels from them since currently you are only getting UIViews which have no way of responding to setText because they do implement on it